# "Mancare all'appello" per esprimere che mancano persone o cose di cui c'è bisogno: si tratta di un uso improprio?

Tags: word-usage

Su [questa notizia di Euronews](https://it.euronews.com/2020/04/28/covid-19-braccianti-rumeni-verso-germania-e-regno-unito-l-italia-sta-perdendo-la-corsa), pubblicata alcuni mesi fa, ho letto (corsivo mio):

> I voli speciali sono stati organizzati da adesso fino a giugno dai produttori; il sindacato degli agricoltori ha stimato che **mancano all'appello** 70 mila lavoratori stagionali, con la situazione complicata dal blocco per l'emergenza Covid-19.

Quando ho letto questa frase, mi sono subito chiesta: perché si usa "mancano all'appello"? Non potrebbe essere semplicemente "mancano"?

Poi ho cercato ["appello" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/appello) e ho trovato questa accezione:

> Il chiamare più persone per nome, secondo un ordine stabilito (per lo più alfabetico), per accertarsi che siano presenti o per altri motivi: *fare l’a*. (degli studenti, dei soldati, ecc.); *a. dei caduti*, rito commemorativo; *rispondere, mancare, presentarsi* o *non presentarsi all’a*. (*mancare all’a*. è anche modo eufem. per annunciare la morte di un soldato, di qualcuno dei partecipanti a un’impresa rischiosa, e sim.)

Tuttavia, è chiaro che, nel contesto dell'articolo sopra citato, non si sta chiamando a una serie di persone per nome né si sta annunciando la morte di un soldato.

La mia domanda sarebbe: è usuale usare questa espressione in questo modo, cioè, per indicare che manca gente per fare qualcosa (in questo caso 70 mila persone per lavorare in modo stagionale nel settore agricolo)?

Ricercando un po' con Google, ho trovato anche esempi in cui quello che "manca all'appello" sono soldi, mascherine, scivoli e altalene per bambini, ecc.

Ecco alcuni esempi tratti da parecchi giornali, ma se ne possono trovare molti di più:

> - Rette dell'asilo nido e servizi scolastici, mancano all'appello 1,1 milioni di euro ([Fonte](https://lasentinella.gelocal.it/ivrea/cronaca/2020/06/26/news/rette-dell-asilo-nido-e-servizi-scolastici-mancano-all-appello-1-1-milioni-di-euro-1.39009815)).
> - Mancano all'​appello 400 mila mascherine, sospesa la distribuzione a Torino ([Fonte](https://www.torinoggi.it/2020/05/15/mobile/leggi-notizia/argomenti/cronaca-11/articolo/mancano-allappello-400-mila-mascherine-sospesa-la-distribuzione-a-torino.html)).
> - Aree ludiche senza giochi: nei giardini pubblici mancano all'appello scivoli ed altalene ([Fonte](http://www.romatoday.it/politica/aree-giochi-mancano-altalene-scivoli.html)).

Si tratta forse di un uso improprio dell'espressione che, per qualche ragione, è diventato usuale?

Comment: È un  abuso della metafora. Piuttosto comune, purtroppo.

Comment: Beh, la parola appello indica che c'è bisogno, rafforza l'idea della mancanza. E' una forma più colorita.

Answer (score 1):

***[Mancare all’appello](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/mancare-allappello),*** dal De Mauro:

> 1. ***di qualcuno,*** *non esserci ancora: manca solo lui all’appello | essere deceduto.*

> 2. ***di qualcosa,***  *venire meno, essere scomparso: dopo la festa mancava all’appello un portacenere d’argento.*

È un comune modo di dire che si riferisce all’appello scolastico.

Comment: Se ho capito bene queste definizioni, riferito a cose, il significato non è che mancano perché ce n'è bisogno, ma che sono sparite (quindi,  andrebbe bene per i soldi se sono stati rubati). E per persone si usa quando qualcuno non è ancora arrivato o quando è morto, non quando manca gente per fare qualcosa, no?

Comment: @Charo - si può usare in tutte le  situazione in cui persone o cose dovrebbero esserci, ma per qualche motivo non ci sono. Ad esempio mancano i soldi per fare gli asili, mancano le mascherine e i giochi dei bambini. È un modo per enfatizzare la mancanza di qualcosa qualsiasi sia il motivo.

Comment: Già, si riferisce all'appello a scuola, in caserma e simili, dove ci dovrebbe essere della gente per fare qualcosa. Quando c'è un allarme sul posto di lavoro si fanno uscire le persone e poi si fa l'appello (regola di sicurezza, per verificare che nessuno sia rimasto nell'incendio o altro pericolo).